# Spring Integration HTTPOutboundGateway :: Connection pool and connectionTimeout,soTimeout,maxTotalConnections

Tags: spring-integration

We are in the process of converting mule based application to spring, in the existing code we've used mule HttpsConnector to consume third party services, we would like do same thing using Spring Http Outbound Gateway.. 
org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Here, my question is, 
How to enable HTTP Connection pooling?
How to set props like connectionTimeout,soTimeout,maxTotalConnections

This is what I am trying to do, But here we can't inject  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient in requestFactory

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Integration `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` provides `setRequestFactory()` option to inject. You can then select any convenient `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation, for example `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
 * {@link org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory} implementation that
 * uses <a href="http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/">Apache HttpComponents
 * HttpClient</a> to create requests.
 *
 * <p>Allows to use a pre-configured {@link HttpClient} instance -
 * potentially with authentication, HTTP connection pooling, etc.
 *
 * <p><b>NOTE:</b> Requires Apache HttpComponents 4.3 or higher, as of Spring 4.0.
```

Example code to create the Pooling HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory:

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory()
{
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(10);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);

    RequestConfig config =
            RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setConnectTimeout(100000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
                    .build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
            HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();

    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}
```

This bean can then be used by either a `RestTemplate` or an `Http.outboundGateway`.

Comment: But it has an `HttpClient` to inject